# Problem using addVectorLayer() in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am confused a bit, using addVectorLayer() in QGIS plugin.

I want to add and display a vector layer, directly when QGIS opens. Hence I am using `addVectorLayer()` in `____init____()` function of my plugin. The problem I am seeing is, the vector layer is loaded in the legend but is not displayed on the canvas. I, manually have to click on "*zoom to layer extent*", to display it.

Any hints on how to solve this problem will be of high help to me.

**NOTE:** If I use either of the below, it works perfect (i.e. the layer is loaded and **displayed as well**).

1. qgis.exe D:/sample.shp at the command prompt **OR**
2. In QGIS Plugin, If I use `addVectorLayer()` on some menu item click

Comment: Have you tried in the initGui method()

Comment: Yes, I have tried putting that in initGui() function too. It does not seem to work..... If I unload the plugin and reload it, then it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried a singleshot QTimer? It is a common technique for running actions once the event loop is ready. I believe setting it to 0 just queues your timer action.

Comment: oh great !!... Thanks Dakcarto... that worked (using 0 still does not display the layer. Only 280ms & above helps). But, I wonder why QGIS doesnt display without using any trick !! i.e without a mouse click or timers, etc, etc ?

Comment: Please write the solution as an answer. Thank you.